# Does the following sequence of min-max converge?

Tags: limits, statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a standard Normal variable. Let $\mathbb{E}$ denote expectation with respect to $X$.

Consider
$$
R(\tau) := \inf_{T} \sup_{|\theta| \leq \tau} 
\mathbb{E}[(T(\theta + X) - \theta)^2]
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
R := \inf_{T} \sup_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}[(T(\theta + X) - \theta)^2]
$$
Above the infima range over measurable maps $T$.

Clearly, $\tau \mapsto R(\tau)$ is an nondecreasing map and $R(\tau) \leq R$.
Is it true that
$$
\lim_{\tau \to \infty} R(\tau) = R? 
$$